# chrome extension: create button toolbar

Tags: google-chrome, button, user-interface, google-chrome-extension

I am new at Chrome extension development. I need to create 2 buttons below addressbar. And obviously buttons have some action (e.g. open new tab). I can do it with Firefox but new at chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensions in Chrome have way much strict rules than Firefox's.

In Chrome there is no toolbar API, and Google has good reasons for no having it yet (I'm not discussing its reasons here).

Chrome has InfoBars, but their API is experimental, not available by default.

Some extensions imitate a toolbar using the DOM.  They aren't browser's toolbars, they are floating DIVs on top of screen of every page.

In Chrome extensions can have a button (singular, not plural), either a Browser Action button, or a Page Action button.  If you need 2 buttons, you need to build two extensions.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have already know this fro Google. Thank you for sharing this.